# DataError: No numeric types to aggregate Attempt to Rank alphanumeric value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in a larger dataframe that represent the ID of the record within my database and a hash of PII data that does not have to be unique. What I am trying to achieve is a window-like function that ranks each PII hash based on the ID in ascending order (See example below). However, I am running into an issue with the `groupby().rank()` method chain because these values are both strings. Is there some transformation that I would need to make to achieve this?

```
id | sha256_cpn | rank
2bce | 1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb | 2
1bce | 1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb | 1
3bce | 1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb | 3
```

Here is the error:

`DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

Here is my code:

```
// id = object
// sha256_cpn = object

df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['sha256_cpn', 'id']).groupby('sha256_cpn')['id'].rank(method="first")
```

Comment: are the values of `ids` for particular `sha256_cpn` unique?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Ids are unique, sha256_cpn are non-unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `groupby` on `sha256_cpn` and transform `id` using `Series.factorize`:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('sha256_cpn')['id']\
               .transform(lambda s: s.factorize(sort=True)[0] + 1)
```

Another approach with `sort_values` then `groupby` + `cumcount`:

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['sha256_cpn', 'id'])\
               .groupby('sha256_cpn').cumcount().add(1)
```

---

```
     id                                                        sha256_cpn  rank
0  2bce  1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb     2
1  1bce  1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb     1
2  3bce  1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb     3
```

Comment: This is great. Achieves exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @cphill Happy coding!